# SoapFault - faultcode: '1062' faultstring: 'Shipping method is not available'

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, magento-1.9, android-ksoap2

Hello i am developing an Android app which uses Magento as the backend and i am using SOAP webervice of magento, I have added all the product , customer and customer address information to the cart , But when i try to add the shipping method to the cart , I am getting this error

---

### SoapFault - faultcode: '1062' faultstring: 'Shipping method is not available'

This is the code i am trying with , Please help me to resolve this

```
SoapObject availableShippingMethods = new SoapObject(MAGENTO_NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartShippingList");
availableShippingMethods.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
availableShippingMethods.addProperty("quoteId", quoteId);
env.setOutputSoapObject(availableShippingMethods);
androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
Object resultForAvailableShippingMethods = env.getResponse();
Log.d("AvailableShippingMethods",resultForAvailableShippingMethods.toString());
```

This will give us this output

---

### D/AvailableShippingMethods﹕ shoppingCartShippingMethodEntityArray{item=shoppingCartShippingMethodEntity{code=flatrate_error; carrier=flatrate; carrier_title=Flat Rate; price=0; }; }

below is the code which sets Shipping method to the CartId

```
 SoapObject shippingmethod = new SoapObject(MAGENTO_NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartShippingMethod");
 shippingmethod.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
 shippingmethod.addProperty("quoteId", quoteId);
 shippingmethod.addProperty("shippingMethod", "flatrate_error");//Code for Flatrate shipping method and it is enabled in magento site
 env.setOutputSoapObject(shippingmethod);
 androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
 Log.d("shippingMethod", shippingmethod.toString());
 Object resultforShippingMethod = env.getResponse();
 Log.d("ShippingMethod", resultforShippingMethod.toString());
```

Comment: u can test your web service using [soupUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/) tool

Comment: Check your webservice method name and passed method name both are same or not

Comment: I have retrieved the list of available shipping methods and I gave the exact shipping method name , But still i am not getting

Comment: did u solved this issue? plz let m know how...

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late to answer... but it may help someone in future...

The problem is in the documentation of magento soap v2... When I have gone through the wsdl link, I have noticed somthing as below...

```
<message name="shoppingCartShippingMethodRequest">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="quoteId" type="xsd:int"/>
<part name="method" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="storeId" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

As u can see, there's property **method**. Actually, there we have to add the shipping method...
So u have to change ur code as below...

```
SoapObject shippingmethod = new SoapObject(MAGENTO_NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartShippingMethod");
shippingmethod.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
shippingmethod.addProperty("quoteId", quoteId);
shippingmethod.addProperty("method", "flatrate_error");
env.setOutputSoapObject(shippingmethod);
androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
Log.d("shippingMethod", shippingmethod.toString());
Object resultforShippingMethod = env.getResponse();
Log.d("ShippingMethod", resultforShippingMethod.toString());
```

Comment: ,sir  your answer is valuable regardless of the time ,thanks for the answer , +10 for answer

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of wrong country ID. After entering correct information I am getting two shipping methods (`freeshipping_freeshipping` and `flatrate_flatrate`).

Comment: but we are not entering any country Id here

Answer (score 0):

Before setting shipping method you need to set customer addresses first & in customer addresses you need to enter country id.

Comment: yes i have done this ,, I have entered "IN" for India ..But still getting the same error ,

Comment: Then please check if you have entered address id or not? Previously I used to get code as "flatrate_error" but now I am getting 2 shipping methods i.e. one is freeshipping_freeshipping & and another as flatrate_flatrate.same I am getting in front end too.

Comment: I am using SOAP V2 version , But it is throwing some fault code error while adding customer address info to the cart

Comment: what error code you are getting while adding customer address info to the cart?

Comment: I have added customer address info to the cart except address_id

Comment: what kind of configuration u kept for shipping methods in magento admin panel

Comment: address_id is compulsory and you can fetch it by calling "customerAddressList" method.
For testing purpose we kept flat rate and free shipping methods in magento admin panel so we are getting two shipping method when calling "shoppingCartShippingList" method!

Comment: btw i am still getting 1062 error after correctly setting customer address so in case you get the output after setting customer address then  let me know!